# Viewing Facts and Sources using Ancestry

Tags: ancestry.com, sources

I noticed something today and I wondered if this is a bug, by design, or specific to my tree.

- If I click on the **Marriage Fact** on the left it links to the **Source**:

[image]

- If I click on the **Source** it links to both the **Marriage Fact** and **Spouse** and more:

[image]

This latter presentation is what I would expect anyway and I can't work out why there is a difference. This happens for all marriages in my tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click on an event, it highlights all the sources (there can be more than one) linked to that event.

If you click on a source it highlights all the individuals and events linked to that source.

Comment: Alright, so it is by design. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @AndrewTruckle it would be best if you didn't accept answers so quickly -- it deters people from providing a better one.

Comment: I understand now the one fact to many sources. And one source to many facts. I get it. 

Comment: I take your advice onboard. If I have more questions I will delay .... 

Comment: Another way of looking at it, is that the links shown are just those going out from the object that you click on. Expecting your 1st example to go out to the spouse would be to have 2 stages of links. Possible but potentially messy.